# ionic3 - ios keyboard hide input field on focus until some input is given

Tags: forms, cordova, ionic2, keyboard, ionic3

Please find my below `ionic info` command

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.12
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.0
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2
Node       : v6.11.2
npm        : 3.10.10
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235
```

here is my code.

```
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px;">
        <img src="assets/login/welcome_login_bg.png" />
        <ion-list style="position: initial">
            <form [formGroup]="loginForm">
                <ion-item no-padding class="firstItem">
                    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="username" formControlName="username" type="email" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off">
                    </ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item no-padding class="borderlineremove">
                    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="password" formControlName="password" clearOnEdit="false" type="password" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off">
                    </ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <button class="loginForm" ion-button (click)="validateUser()" full color="danger">
                  <b>Sign In</b>
                </button>
                <ion-row>
                    <div class="forgotPwd"><span (click)="forGotPwd()">Forgot Password?</span></div>
                    <div class="signUp"><span (click)="registration()">Sign Up</span></div>
                </ion-row>
            </form>
        </ion-list>
    </div>
```

Issue:

> When i focus on the keyboard i am not able to move the form above the keyboard until some input is given but in android everything works fine.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking about w/the keyboard - screenshots of desired vs actual behavior would help. Aside: you probably shouldn't need both `[(ngModel)]` and `formControlName` - use either the Reactive Forms "model-driven" approach w/formControls OR the "template-driven" approach; not both.

Comment: in simple words keybord On focus of input field in android and ios is diffrent and i need in ios device to be worked like android funtionality when keyboard is focused @mc01

Comment: The project contains "ionic-plugin-keyboard" plugin. Is it the latest version?

Comment: @clu3Less yes it is but i have also tried using `.scroll-content{ padding-bottom: 0px}` it is not working for me

Comment: Please try after remove style="position: initial" from <ion-list>. or  style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px;" from <div>